# Google Analytics: filter by Page and Service Provider

Tags: regex, google-analytics

In essence, I'm trying to get a report that shows internal vs. external viewing of a particular page. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Go to Content -> Site Content -> Pages
2. Filter by my page '/directory/sub/page.html'
3. Add Advanced Segment where Service Provide contains 'My Companys Service Provider'
4. Add another Advanced Segment where Service Provider matches RegExp '^((?!My Companys Service Provider).)*$'

When I add the last Advanced Segment, I get a (generic) error that state:

Resource is not available. Please try again later.
One or more of the services on which we depend is unavailable. Please try again later after the service has had a chance to recover.

Is my RegExp wrong or does Google Analytics just have a problem with doing reports with Regular Expressions?

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

**Use these two segments**

1st - 
**include** Service Provide contains 'My Companys Service Provider' AND page=='/directory/sub/page.html'

2nd - 
**exclude** Service Provide contains 'My Companys Service Provider' AND page=='/directory/sub/page.html'

Not sure GA supports look-ahead regexs. Your regex may cause multiple calculation cycles